Reason for two approaches to the Simplex method, for the initial point, one with all variables $=0;$ & other having only Non-Basic variables $=0.$
In the text book here, have on pg #26-28, in the tabular form of the Simplex method, seems to have taken, for the Initial point BFS,  all variables (decision & slack) as $=0;$ though at the pages #24-26, for the non-tabular approach, has taken the slack (now, Basic variables) as positive.
Am confused as to how there are two approaches to the Simplex method, one for the tabular approach, and another for the non-tabular approach.
Am I missing something in the tabular form? If yes, what?
Please note that am taking the standard form, of the LPP, i.e. the maximization based; with the initial point as the origin.

You misunderstood the tabular form.

Look at the RHS column, in the first iteration, the basic variable $(x_3,x_4)=(5,12)$ and the non-basic variables take values $0$. The slack variable is non-zero.
Both approaches are doing the same thing, just the way we present it and organize it.
